# Fix selected item highlighter on QTreeWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget that has values in them, which I only want to show a certain number of decimals but keep the precision for calculation purposes. I have it working correctly, but the highlighting of the selected items are messed up and show white around the cell that has been drawn.

How can I fix the highlighting so that is solid blue for the entire row?

```
class InitialDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    'Changes number of decimal places in gas analysis self.chosen table'
    def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nDecimals = decimals
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            try:
                number = float(value)
                painter.drawText(option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter , "{:.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals))
            except:
                QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 observations in its implementation:

- If you only want to change what the format as the text is shown then you should not override the [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#paint) method since it not only paints the text but also the background, icons, etc. The [`drawDisplay()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#drawDisplay) method must be override.
- If you are only going to apply the change to a column it is better to set the delegate using the [`setItemDelegateForColumn()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) method

Considering the above, then the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class InitialDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    "Changes number of decimal places in gas analysis self.chosen table"

    def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nDecimals = decimals

    def drawDisplay(self, painter, option, rect, text):
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        try:
            number = float(text)
            text = "{:.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals)
        except:
            pass
        super().drawDisplay(painter, option, rect, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(columnCount=3)
    delegate = InitialDelegate(2, w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate) # <---
    w.setHeaderLabels(["Gas Component", "Molecular Weight", "Mol%"])
    it = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Hexane", "86.1777", ""])
    w.addTopLevelItem(it)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Plus:**

If you want to do the same but using [`QStyledItemDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) then the solution is override [`initStyleOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption):

```py
class InitialDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    "Changes number of decimal places in gas analysis self.chosen table"

    def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nDecimals = decimals

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        try:
            text = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            number = float(text)
            option.text = "{:.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals)
        except:
            pass
```